# Gmap API: Draw Polygon automatically based on saved polygon points

Tags: google-maps

I am working on application in which i have integrated drawing polygon functionality. Drawing polygon functionality is working great but i need to built another functionality where user can save the polygon search. For that to that to work i need to save polygon paths points which i have already saved now i need to know is there function in gmap to which we pass draw polygon points and it draws the polygon automatically or is there any workaround to built this functionality.

Looking forward for your response.

Comment: Why don't you just draw the [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) with your saved points? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @geocodezip thats what i am asking how to draw the polygon with save points?i mean is there any function in gmap api to which i pass save points it draws the polygon or any other way to do it.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  That is the way the [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) constructor works, you pass in an array of [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) objects that define the Polygon (your "saved points").  Perhaps you could post the code that you are using and having difficulty with.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip your comment really help me to Draw Polygon automatically based on saved polygon points.